# NULL Value Kills Code or Repeats Previous Value

Tags: php, mysqli

#### Situation:

I am writing a code to display data from 2 different tables and 2 different sets of data from a single table if the condition is met.

#### Problem:

If the first `$row[7]` is `NULL` it dies and doesn't continue.

If any value after the first `$row[7]` is `NULL` or `$row2[5]` is `NULL` it repeats the previous value of that row. If the value is `NULL` I just want it to be displayed as blank and continue on to the next row.

#### Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM roster WHERE uic='".$uic."'";
if($result = $mysqli->query($sql,MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT)) {
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    if($row[7]) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE id=$row[7]";
        $result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2,MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
        $row2 = $result2->fetch_row();
        if($row2[5]) {
            $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE id=$row2[5]";
            $result3 = $mysqli->query($sql3,MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
            $row3 = $result3->fetch_row();
        }
    }
    echo '
        <tr bgcolor="#a3a3a3">
          <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
          <td>'.$row[2].'</td>
          <td>'.$row[3].'</td>
          <td>'.$row[4].'</td>
          <td>'.$row2[1].'</td>
          <td>'.$row2[2].'</td>
          <td>'.$row3[1].'</td>
          <td>'.$row3[2].'</td>
          <td>'.$row2[9].'</td>
          <td>'.$row2[7].'</td>
          <td>'.$row2[8].'</td>
        </tr>
         ';
    }
}
```

Comment: It may not like multiple cursors on the database, but that should be seen in warnings or notices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT fields FROM roster r 
        LEFT JOIN equipment e1 ON e1.id=r.row7
        LEFT JOIN equipment e2 ON e2.id=e1.row5
        WHERE uic='$uic'";
```

`fields` consists of comma delimited list of fields you need, from all 3 tables, prefixed with table aliases, like `r.id, e1.name, e1.price, e2.name as e2name, e2.price as e2price`
`row7` and `row5` have to be renamed to real field names.

Comment: `row7` and `row5` have to be renamed to real field names.